# Unable to execute join with a table and an array on Vertica database

Tags: database, vertica

I am trying to join an array with a table in vertica DB but fails to execute the join saying there's a syntax near ')'. The query I am trying to execute is mentioned below.

```
Select v.valueId, m.name 
From (values (1), (2), (3), (4), (5)) v(valueId)
left Join resource m
on m.id = v.valueId
```

The query runs fine on Postgres DB but fails to run on Vertica DB.Please help me with this query. Are there any alternatives to achieve the same thing with a different query? Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I dont know Vertica - does it have a Table Value Constructors? If not:

```
Select v.valueId, m.name 
From (
    select 1 as valueid
    union select 2
    union select 3
    union select 4
    union select 5
    ) v
left Join resource m on m.id = v.valueId
```